# Extract integer from a string in objective c

Tags: ios

i have a string which has both numeric and character value.

Like:  `string = abc1234`

Now I want to get only the integer part from it:

i.e. `1234`

How can I do this? I have tried the following with no luck:

```
  NSString *str = @"abc123";
  int s = [str intValue];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this function

```
- (NSString *)extractNumberFromText:(NSString *)text
{
  NSCharacterSet *nonDigitCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
  return [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonDigitCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

It will help you.Thankyou